# X370: Only half of my memory is available

Tags: uefi, ram, 17.04, amd-processor

I just installed a workstation with
- Ryzen 7 1800x
- Asrock X370 Professional Gaming, freshly updated UEFI 2.20
- 4x 16GB Kingston KVR24E17D8/16MA PC4-2400 ECC RAM

The BIOS detects all 4 RAM bars and tells me 65xxx MB RAM.
Despite the fact that the manual says that 4x dual rank is only supported for 2133, the UEFI does not set that automatically. However, it does not change anything if I set it to 2133 manually.
Everything else (Memtest86 from the Kubuntu installer, Kubuntu 17.04 'free -h') reports 32GB RAM BUT dmidecode reports 4x 16GB RAM just fine. I don't see anything unnormal there, it even tells me "ECC type: Multi-bit ECC" four times.

I did try to remove DIMM 1&3 and DIMM 2&4, and I get 32GB in both cases, so it doesn't seem to be a general problem with slots or DIMMs.

Any ideas?

Comment: And you think that falsely results in the right result?

Comment: Oh wait a second, I'm sorry, I was confused. Never mind :)